# Primitive root mod $2p^k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

We say that $g$ is a primitive root mod $n$ if $\langle g\rangle=U_n$.I want to prove the following theorem:

**Theorem**

If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$,then either $g$ or $g+p^k$ is a primitive root modulo $2p^k$.Moreover,we can guarantee that the odd one out of $g$ and $g+p^k$ will be the one which is primitive root.

Can someone provide me hints on how to proceed.I think I can do it myself if some hint is provided.

Comment: Hint: only the odd one can be a primitive root, then count the number of relative primes modulo $2p^k$.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar FYI, a couple of closely related questions on this site are [Primitive roots of odd primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98647/602049) and [Proving that $r+p^{\alpha}$ is a primitive root of $2p^{\alpha}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2827761/602049).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Euler function $\phi(2p^k)=(p-1)p^{k-1}=\phi(p^k)$. Suppose that $g$ is odd. Then it is coprime with $2p^k$. Let $s$ be the order of $g \pmod{2p^k}$. Then $s$ divides $(p-1)p^{k-1}$, and $g^s\equiv 1\pmod{p^k}$. Then $s$ is divisible by $\phi(p^k)=(p-1)p^{k-1}$. Hence $s=(p-1)p^{k-1}$ and $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod{2p^k}$. Now suppose $g$ is even. Then $g+p^k$ is odd and $\equiv g\pmod{p^k}$, so $g+p^k$ is an odd primitive root for $p^k$ and we can proceed as before: $g+p^k$ is a primitive root for $2p^k$.